# Getting error while Parsing a JSON Object In Android

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

Anyone one have idea how to parse this JSON response .Also tell me why i have `[enter you code here]`in my JSON response.I have no idea from where this line is coming .

my Logcat is :

```
  03-30 09:49:16.757: W/dalvikvm(13459): VFY: unable to resolve static method 604: Landroid/net/TrafficStats;.setThreadStatsTag (I)V
03-30 09:49:16.757: D/dalvikvm(13459): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
03-30 09:49:16.976: D/dalvikvm(13459): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 47% free 2997K/5639K, external 507K/517K, paused 3ms+4ms
03-30 09:49:18.976: I/global(13459): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1110ms.
03-30 09:49:18.992: D/RegisterActivity(13459): Register Response: [Enter code here]{"tag":"register","error":false,"uid":"5518cec863a130.84373662","user":{"name":"kku","email":"kkajhg.jun@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-30 00:19:20","updated_at":null}}

03-30 09:49:18.992: D/RegisterActivity(13459): <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->

03-30 09:49:18.992: D/RegisterActivity(13459): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>

03-30 09:49:18.992: D/RegisterActivity(13459): <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

03-30 09:49:18.992: D/RegisterActivity(13459): user added
03-30 09:49:19.000: W/System.err(13459): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 8 of [Enter code here]{"tag":"register","error":false,"uid":"5518cec863a130.84373662","user":{"name":"kku","email":"kkajhg.jun@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-03-30 00:19:20","updated_at":null}}

03-30 09:49:19.000: W/System.err(13459): <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->

03-30 09:49:19.000: W/System.err(13459): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>

03-30 09:49:19.000: W/System.err(13459): <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

03-30 09:49:19.000: W/System.err(13459):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:436)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:99)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at com.example.classroom.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:125)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at com.example.classroom.RegisterActivity$3.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:1)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-30 09:49:19.007: W/System.err(13459):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-30 09:49:19.015: W/System.err(13459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 09:49:19.015: W/System.err(13459):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-30 09:49:19.015: W/System.err(13459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-30 09:49:19.015: W/System.err(13459):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-30 09:49:19.015: W/System.err(13459):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 09:50:34.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(13459): Can't open keycharmap file
03-30 09:50:34.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(13459): Error loading keycharmap file
03-30 09:50:34.953: W/KeyCharacterMap(13459): Using default keymap
03-30 09:50:35.234: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13459): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-30 09:52:17.656: D/dalvikvm(13459): GC_EXPLICIT freed 216K, 47% free 3027K/5639K, external 507K/517K, paused 46ms
```

`Register Response:`is text from my java code for logcat. For your info I am using volley.

my java source  code for parsing the json is:

```
pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response);
                    hideDialog();
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "user added");


                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {
                            // User successfully stored in MySQL
                            // Now store the user in sqlite
                            String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                            String name = user.getString("name");
                            String email = user.getString("email");
                            String created_at = user
                                    .getString("created_at");
```

Here is my php code :

```
    index.php
<?php

/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * 
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    } else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: post your logcat rather than the screenshot

Comment: you mean screenshot of my whole logcat @PramodYadav

Comment: No, not a screenshot. He means the actual text in from the logcat window.

Comment: post your url where from you are fetching this or just copy the Json from your logcat and post here

Comment: see the php code (from here i'm fetching the response) @ashutiwari4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code you can use for now which will skip [Enter your code] for now

```
        response = response.split("]")[1];
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
        String tag = jo.getString("tag");
        boolean error = jo.getBoolean("error");
        String uid = jo.getString("uid");
        JSONObject jo1 = jo.getJSONObject("user");
        String name = jo1.getString("name");
        String email = jo1.getString("email");
        String createdAt = jo1.getString("created_at");
        String updatedAt = jo1.getString("updated_at");

        System.out.println("Tag: " + tag + " error: " + error + " name: "
                + name + " email: " + email);
```

I think before encoding data to JSON from php you should print data and check what are you sending. It might possible you are sending wrong data cause volly doesn't interfere.

Comment: thnx a lot bro it's working ...it's a relief ...but from where this line is coming...if you find anything regarding this ...plss tell me bro...again thnx a lot

Comment: "[enter your code here] " i'm talking about this line.....if you found anything plss...tell it will be vry helpful

Comment: from your service. You have to print result before encoding it to JSON. 
Search for this line in your android project as well server side script [enter your code here]. You'll get it